# get shape of tensor as array in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a saved model from which I want the final weights that are applied in the final layer. I have loaded the graph and know the where the tensor is but I can't get the shape of the tensor as an array. I know the array has the shape 2048x6. How do I get the actual values like so
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]...]. Thanks

Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('_retrain_checkpoint.meta')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("final_retrain_ops/weights/final_weights:0")

print(tensor)
print(tf.TensorShape(tensor.get_shape()).as_list()




>>>Tensor("final_retrain_ops/weights/final_weights:0", shape=(2048, 6), dtype=float32_ref)
>>>(2048, 6)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. `print( tensor.get_shape().as_list() )` will give you the tensor's *shape*. But from your question it's unclear if you want the values (i.e. the weights in this case) instead?

Comment: sorry about the confusion I want the values.

Answer (score 0):

To print the values of the weight tensor, you can do the following:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( tensor ) )
```

[`sess.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) *evaluates* the tensor(s) in it argument, which here just means it will print the values.

There is a bit of an issue, however, that your code only loads the structure of the graph (`tf.train.import_meta_graph('_retrain_checkpoint.meta')`), not the pretrained values. Therefore you get the error that you're trying to use uninitialized values.

You need to have something like:

```
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

to load it, right after `sess` has been defined, and of course, you need to point to the correct checkpoint directory instead of `./`.

So something like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    print( sess.run( tensor ) )
```

Comment: Updated answer as a response to your comment.